# Multiplicação em Python usando recurção sem interações do tipo `while` e `for`

Tags: python

Estou a escrever um código de uma calculadora de multiplicação que deve usar apenas operadores aritméticos, no intervalo de  `-10 >= x <= 10` e deve sempre fazer as contas sob a melhor performance possível, ex.: `3x2 = 3 + 3` e não `3x2 = 2 + 2 + 2`. O meu problema é que eu não posso usar de maneira alguma os comandos `while` e `for`, só posso usar os operadores `+` e `-`. A minha ideia era primeiro fazer usando `while` e `for` e depois retirá-los, mas não estou conseguindo ver como isso seria possível. Além disso, preciso dar print nos intermediários da conta, por exemplo: `3 x 10` eu teria que dar um print de algo parecido com: `10; 20; 30` e não faço ideia de como fazer isso, talvez seja algo que se abra a possibilidade ao conseguir fazer sem `while` e `for`, mas não sei. Agradeço qualquer ajuda, estou bem enrolado com isso.

```
def erro_numero():
    print(' ')
    print('O número deve ser igual ou estar entre -10 e 10.')


def erro_letra():
    print(' ')
    print('O valor deve ser um número inteiro.')


def erro_0():
    print(' ')
    print('Não é possível dividir por zero.')


def primeiro_numero():
    try:
        x = int(input('Digite o valor do primeiro número: '))
        if x < -10 or x > 10:
            erro_numero()
            return primeiro_numero()
        else:
            return x

    except:
        erro_letra()
        return primeiro_numero()

def segundo_numero():
    try:
        z = int(input('Digite o valor do segundo número: '))
        if z < -10 or z > 10:
            erro_numero()
            return segundo_numero()
        else:
            return z
    except:
        erro_letra()
        return segundo_numero()


def produto(p, s):
    if p == 0 or s == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        sinal = True
        if (p < 0) != (s < 0):
            sinal = False

        if p < 0:
            p = 0 - p

        if s < 0:
            s = 0 - s

        resultado = 0
        if p > s:
            for i in range(s):           #Aqui o for e a função range() precisam ser removidas
                resultado = resultado + p
        else:
            for i in range(p):           #Aqui o for e a função range() precisam ser removidas
                resultado = resultado + s

        if sinal == False:
            return 0 - resultado
        else:
            return resultado


def print_do_valor(pro):          
    print('O valor do produto é:', pro)


while True:                   #Essa parte do código é só para fazer rodar
    p = primeiro_numero()
    s = segundo_numero()
    pro = produto(p, s)
    print_do_valor(pro)
```

Comment: é possível fazer "sem while e for" - mas não é "saudável" - não si se a intenção de quem passou o exercídio era fazer vocês exercitarem um monte de "if" e "elif" e copiar colar código - mas defintiivamente, não é uma boa forma de aprender a programar - estruturas de repetição são algo MUITO fundamental em programação - e é mito mais importantante dominar as mesmas do que copiar e colar código igual 10 vezes fazendo "if"s.

Comment: tem uma forma que exercíta sim um bom "pensar sobre programação" sem for nem while, que é simular o laço usando recursão. - se essa é a intenção pelo menos não fica um monte de repetições. Seu professor falou em funções e função chamando ela mesma?

Comment: Falou sim, ele disse que era pra fazer de maneira recursiva, tanto que boa parte do código está escrito de maneira recursiva. Como que, nesse caso, eu faria pra fazer a conta e o print dos resultados usando a recursividade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esclarecidas as dúvidas no comentário, dá pra escrever uma resposta que pode ser produtiva:

Poder executar tarefas de forma repetitiva é possivelmente a mais importante característica da computação digital. Por exemplo, só para "pintar" a tela onde esta resposta está sendo lida, o computador está transferindo as informações de cerca de 2 milhões de pixels (~6 milhões de bytes) entre áreas de memória que representam o buffer de vídeo, e isso 30 vezes por segundo (pelo menos). Imagine fazer isso sem repetição?

Dito isso, as estruturas de repetição que existem em todas as linguagens modernas (no caso do Python `while` e `for`), já são abstrações em cima do que a CPU realmente "faz" por baixo dos panos: tudo que ela faz são saltos condicionais - no código de máquina a CPU subtrai um valor de um número, e decide se salta para a execução continuar dentro do laço ou se continua em frente, para outro trecho do programa.

Linguagens chamadas "funcionais" - que de forma subjetiva podemos dizer que são mais próximas da codificação usada na matemática moderna, podem não ter "while" e "for", escolhendo usar a construção de "funções" - que todas as linguagens modernas também tem, e são importantíssimas, para representar também todas as repetições.

Isso não ajuda a "aprender python". Não ajuda a "aprender programação" - mas ajuda a entender "o que é possível fazer com programação" e ajuda a entender melhor funções.

Então primeira coisa: esqueça a parte da "impressão" - o que você precisa é primeiro calcular o valor da multiplicação chamando funções.  Quando já tiver o valor calculado , aí sim, você imprime só com um "print".

Então, qual a ideia de "repetição usando recursão"? Simples - uma função recebe seus parâmetros, e verifica se chegou ao fim dos cálculos que precisa fazer - se sim, retorna o valor encontrado (*).  Se não, faz uma interação dos cálculos - o equivalente ao código que estaria no corpo de um 'for' ou 'while' e na última linha retorna o valor que ela mesma retorna, com os valores modificados, e indicando que falta uma interação a menos para terminar o processo.  Quando chegar na última interação, aquele "retorno" que indiquei com (*) vai atravessando e passando pelo "return" de todas as chamadas anteriores.

Há duas formas de escrever isso, equivalentes - uma que fica mais parecida com um "for" normal:

```
def multiplica(op1, contador, resultado_parcial=0):
    if contador == 0:
        return resultado_parcial
    resultado_parcial = resultado_parcial + op1
    return multiplica(op1, contador - 1, resultado_parcial)
```

E, refatorando um pouco, temos uma forma que fica mais "simples e elegante" e mais parecida com o uso de funções em matemática :

```
def multiplica(op1, op2):
    if op2 == 1:
        return op1
    return op1 + multiplica(op1, op2 - 1)
```

o resultado é exatamente o mesmo, e são muito parecidas, mas nessa última a operação é feita na ordem "inversa": a soma mais "interna" é feita antes, e, na hora de retornar, uma última operação é executada em cada chamada da função ao longo da cadeia. Isso é, numa multiplicacao de "4 X 3", depois da terceira chamada com "4, 1", a linha do return da chamada com "4, 2" é executada, faz a soma de "4" com o resultado interno  e retorna para a chamada mais externa "4, 3".

Em Python isso não faz nenhuma diferença - mas em algumas linguagens funcionais, quando não tem nenhuma operação a mais para ser feita com o valor do retorno da chamada recursiva (como está escrito na listagem de cima - o valor retornado mais interno só é retornado *direto* para quem chamou "multiplicar" pela primeira vez), a linguagem pode fazer uma otimização chamada "tail call optimization", em que todas as informações das chamadas intermediárias são "limpas" - o último return, mais interno, já devolve valor direto para quem chamou "multiplicar" de fora.

Em Python, código recursivo não fica muito otimizado - é tranquilo usar quando melhora a legibilidade, por exemplo, para buscar arquivos em árvores de diretórios, ou dados em estruturas JSON de listas e dicionários aninhados - mas cada chamada de função recursiva consome de 100 a 1000 vezes mais recursos computacionais que voltar ao início de um "for" "while", criando um objeto que se chama "Frame"  com o estado da função chamada. Então esse tipo de conta, só é bom para fins didáticos mesmo.

Dada a explicação, e como funciona a mutiplicação, você deve conseguir terminar seu exercício: tem que lidar com os operando negativos, que eu não trato acima, nem com otimizar a execução para fazer menos chamadas.